# Regex to format dates and replace underscores?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a regex for URL rewrite to convert the dates to slashes with full year, underscores to dashes, and to leave off the extension.

This is an example to start with:
`/news/14-10-19/Top_Items_of_Yesterday.php`

Then trying to end up with this:
`/news/2014/10/19/Top-Items-of-Yesterday`

Can anyone help with this scenario?

Comment: Is `/news/` a directory?

Comment: Which server are you using? (Apache, IIS, ...)

Comment: You can use this RegExp: `/([^/]+)/(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/(.+)\.php` and this replace: `/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5`.

Comment: I'm using IIS but I think any regex would work. Also /news/is a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/(.+?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/20%2/%3/%4/%5 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: what about `my.script.php`? :D